# Google Apps From : email address, spoofed how?

Tags: email-spoofing

We use google apps for business to host our business emails, using our own custom domain `mysite.com`.

I view my emails via gmail.com

I recently received an email from `me@mysite.com` to `me@mysite.com` stating id been hacked etc.. send BTC.. They even had a password that i had used previously. (The password they had was obviously from a data dump of a hacked site and as we use a password manager to create unique passwords im not too concerned.)

My concern is how they where able to spoof the from address ? I thought google apps for business had some default protection against this ? How can i protect against this ?

Comment: We can't really help just by the short description you provided. Only the header information will tell you and us what actually is going on.

Answer (score -1):

It's a common problem with email providers, something which gmail, outlook, yahoo etc all suffer from. They don't have adequate SFP/DMARC protections so it's possible to spoof an email from any @gmail.com account via a service such as SendGrid.

Like you've already identified, they probably found your old password in a dump online and are mass emailing out spoofed emails. An interesting new type of scam.

Comment: Gmail has more than adequate SPF/DMARC protections. SendGrid does not "spoof" anything.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here schroeder, you have a very good ranking on stack exchange, but have you actually tested this? Because i've used SendGrid to spoof emails from both gmail.com and outlook.com in the past few months. I went and checked now and they have actually updated their protections in the last 2 days (outlook:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/anti-spoofing-protection). So this shouldn't actually be possible now, but certainly was prior to this.

Comment: Then you might need to define what you mean by "spoof"